# 404 no arquivo css após mapeamento do spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Boa noite a todos!

Não consigo acessar o css da minha aplicação em spring, mesmo após mapear resouce, segue códigos:

```
    @Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {  
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}

@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}
```

E Segue o html do mesmo:

```
<link href="resources/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

Qual será o problema, pois mesmo após maper não consigo acessar o css.

Comment: Onde você colocou seu arquivo css?

Comment: O arquivo css está no resources dentro da pasta src/main.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que você está mapeando o arquivo para uma pasta chamada `resources` dentro da pasta `src/main/webapp`(que é o local indicado para esses aquivos), mas está colocando os arquivos na pasta `src/main/resources` (que indicado para arquivos da sua aplicação, como arquivos de configuração).

Crie uma pasta `resources` dentro da pasta `src/main/webapp`e coloque sua pasta `css` lá dentro.

Caso você queira, por algum motivo, manter seus arquivos `css` dentro da pasta `src/main/resources`, crie dentro dessa pasta uma outra pasta chamada `resources`, coloque sua pasta `css` lá dentro e mude o mapeamento para:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/resources/");
}
```

Comment: Obrigado Felipe!

Answer (score 0):

Olá, ao criar os links para os resources é uma boa prática utilizar o contexto da aplicação. Você pode usar jstl para inputar o contexto dinamicamente, então você pode escrever este link da seguinte maneira:

```
   <link href="<c:url value='resources/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.css'/>" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

Para que a tag < c:url /> funcione você precisa importar a biblioteca core do jstl.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

Comment: Eu já tentei por este processo mais não consigo, a unica forma que consegui foi criar uma pasta resources dentro da pasta webapp.